# PrimeFaces , themeroller, error when theme changed

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, themeroller

I added all-themes.jar in pom.xml, it works fine with one theme in web.xml.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>excite-bike</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But when I declare themes in the web.xml as dynamic in use of EL2.2

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>#{userSettingsController.currentTheme.name}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

it get the below error with theme roller when I change the theme in drop down list.

```
Apr 20, 2013 5:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/timetable] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'start' of flow 'teacher'] with root cause
javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-" library
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeTheme(HeadRenderer.java:130)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:92)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:829)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.render(FlowLifecycle.java:80)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:90)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I tried three approaches, one from showcase, another from primefaces book, and last one from some tutorial. I always get the same error. I even copied code exactly like in the examples but still nothing, I assume I'm missing some settings in web.xml or faces-config.xml... Can anyone help me?
BIG THANKS!
I work with Spring 3.1, primefaces 3.5, jsf 2.0.7.

**Edit:**
- it works when I navigate to another page but without changing starting theme
- I can change theme but when theme is changed and I navigate to another page the above error
- it does not matter what is the default theme, it will load and I can navigate whole app as long as the default theme is not changed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

UI page(xhtml,...):

```
                    <p:themeSwitcher style="width: 200px" value="#{topBean.theme}"  id="defaultSwitcher">  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose Theme" itemValue="" />  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{topBean.themes}" />
                        <p:ajax listener="#{topBean.saveTheme}" />  
                    </p:themeSwitcher>
```

Bean:

```
private Map<String, String> themes;
    private String theme;
    private GuestPreferences gp;
    public TopBean(){
        theme = "eggplant";
    }

    public Map<String, String> getThemes() {
        return themes;
    }

    public String getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }

    public GuestPreferences getGp() {
        return gp;
    }

    public void setThemes(Map<String, String> themes) {
        this.themes = themes;
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

    public void setGp(GuestPreferences gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        gp = new GuestPreferences();
        theme = gp.getTheme();
        themes = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        themes.put("Aristo", "aristo");
        themes.put("Black-Tie", "black-tie");
        ...
    }

    public void saveTheme() {
        gp.setTheme(theme);
    }
```

Comment: Hi RongNK, this is exactly the approach I adopted in my code. I tried both stateful examples (ajax and page refres) and also the one from PrimeFaces Cookbook. Always the same error, basically as you can see from this line: **javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-" library** "primefaces-???" cannot find the jar, but only when page is refreshed. I have all-themes.jar in my pom.xml

Comment: I mean the jar is there but the parameter of new theme name is not passed to the new view...

Comment: You use Maven, so you reference: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=18928

Comment: I use Maven, but as you can see from the error above, it finds the jar. But when I navigate to another view, the value of the new theme is missing **primefaces-**, so it is like it for some reason does not hold the value between views.

Answer (score 0):

I had **exactly** the same problem - themeSwitcher wasn't inside form element so it was working as long as i didn't do navigation. Then it broke up simply because empty String was set as current theme - that's why i was getting message:

**javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-" library**

and not something like:

**javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-cupertino" library**

So, if you have this problem, first of all check that `<p:themeSwitcher>` is surrounded with `<h:form>` element.